# for_each to concatenate string, to all strings within a vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm in the process of learning c++, so naturally i've been fooling around trying to figure out what i can, and can't do. I've written a small piece of code to mess around with lambdas and strings, but it seems to be giving me some issues :S.

I have two string stored in the vector, one is chocolate and the other is vanilla. I want to concatenate fudge to the end. I'm declaring the associated libraries. Everything compiles and runs. But nothing concatenates :S Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
void main()
{

     vector<string> ramzy;
     ramzy.push_back("chocolate");
     ramzy.push_back("vanilla");

     for_each(ramzy.begin(),ramzy.end(),
         [](string word)->string{
             string i = word + " fudge";
             return (i);
         } );

     cout << ramzy[0] << endl << ramzy[1] << endl;

}
```

The output is show below:

```
chocolate
vanilla
```

Desired output is show below:

```
Chocolate Fudge
Vanilla Fudge
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

> ```
> std::for_each
> ```
>
> Applies the given function object `f` to the result of dereferencing
>   every iterator in the range `[first, last)`, in order. **If `InputIt` is a
>   mutable iterator, `f` may modify the elements of the range through the
>   dereferenced iterator**. **If f returns a result, the result is ignored**.

So, you have to change your lambda to:

```
[](string& word)
{
    word += " fudge";
}
```

Comment: It works without a for_each rewirte. I guess i need to relearn my lambda :S But thanks you for the help.

Comment: @Ramzicle *"I guess I need to relearn my lambda"* - No, only how the standard algorithms work, nothing to do with the lambda.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of for_each, use transform for your need.

```
std::transform(ramzy.begin(),ramzy.end(),ramzy.begin(),[](const std::string& str) 
          { 
                return str + " fudge"; 
           });
```

Comment: I prefer `std::transform` to `std::for_each` but you better not be taking a `const std::string&` into your lambda.